# Inhomogeneous First Order PDE with boundary condition

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I'm having some trouble solving the following PDE:

\begin{equation}
u_x+u_y=1, u(y,\frac{y}{2})=y
\end{equation}

I know I can use the total differential to find a general solution:

\begin{equation}
\frac{du}{dx}=u_x+u_y\frac{dy}{dx}\\
\end{equation}

So
\begin{align}
\frac{du}{dx}&=1\\
\frac{dy}{dx}&=1\\
u&=x+C
\end{align}
where $C$ is a constant. How do I use the boundary data from here to find the solution though?

Comment: You obtained $u(x,y)=x+C$ . According to the condition $u(y,\frac{y}{2})=y$ put $x=y$ in it. So, $y+C=y$ which implies $C=0$.

Answer (score 2):

a more general solution to $u_x + u_y = 1$ is $u(x,y)= Ax + (1-A)y+C$

the use of the variable $y$ in the expression of the boundary condition is unfortunate , we could say $u(p, \frac{p}{2}) = p$ for all real numbers $p$.

plug that into the general solution, keeping in mind that this is an identity in $p$, by equating coefficients you should get that $C=0$ and $A=1$

so $$u(x,y)=x$$

Comment: how do you arrive at that general solution?